# How to add a button to a JFrame Gui

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

I'm trying to add a button to a frame gui.
i tried making a panel and adding it to that, but it does not work.
please help!

here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Agui extends JFrame {
    public Agui() {
        setTitle("My Gui");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button;
        JPanel panel;

        // my error lines are under the "panel" and  "button"
        // it says i must implement the variables. what does that mean???
        panel.add(button);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Agui a = new Agui();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should initialize it

Comment: You are missing `JButton button = new JButton("click me");` and `JPanel panel = new JPanel();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example Code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Agui extends JFrame {

    public Agui() {

        setTitle("My Gui");
        setSize(400, 400);

        // Create JButton and JPanel
        JButton button = new JButton("Click here!");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        // Add button to JPanel
        panel.add(button);
        // And JPanel needs to be added to the JFrame itself!
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Agui a = new Agui();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

- Create the JButton and JPanel using `new JButton("...");` and `new JPanel()`
- Add the JPanel to the JFrame's content pane using `getContentPane().add(...);`

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
JButton button;
JPanel panel;
```

to:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

You can also pass a `String` value in `JButton()` constructor for that string value to be shown on the `JButton`.

**Example:** `JButton button = new JButton("I am a JButton");`

Answer (score 0):

> **If you can Change this Program, You can adjust the button place also**

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;



public class agui extends JFrame

{

agui()
{
    setTitle("My GUI");
    setSize(400,400);
    setLayout(null);

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Here..!");
    button.setBounds(50,100,100,50); /*Distance from left,           
                      Distance from top,length of button, height of button*/
    add(button);

    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

     JFrame agui = new agui();



}

}
```

***[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6RUL.png)***

Comment: Can you explain how that code solves the original question?